# MPMusicPlayerController fails to play Apple Music songs

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

I am using an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` to enqueue an array of store IDs. This has worked for months now. Earlier today I updated to iOS 14.3, and the player is now failing to play songs.

The code below is the minimal amount needed to replicate the bug:

```swift
// note: repo using any play method you want
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
let descriptor: MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor?

func setup() {
 let storeIDs: [String] = ["lorem", "ipsum"] // fetch real IDs from the API
 descriptor = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(queue: storeIDs)
}

func play() {
 self.player.setQueue(with: descriptor!)
 self.player.play()
}

// Expected: plays song with store ID "lorem"
// Actual: app freezes and I see error logs
```

When I play a song, instead of playing it, the app completely freezes (meaning it doesn't respond to user interaction), and I see the following logs:

```
[SDKPlayback] ASYNC-WATCHDOG-1: Attempting to wake up the remote process
[SDKPlayback] SYNC-WATCHDOG-1: Attempting to wake up the remote process
[SDKPlayback] ASYNC-WATCHDOG-2: Tearing down connection
[SDKPlayback] SYNC-WATCHDOG-2: Tearing down connection
```

The `MPMusicPlayerController` plays music just fine on iOS 14.2.

Can anybody confirm or shed some light on what's going on here?

I filed a TSI/bug report with Apple in the meantime.

Comment: I can at least confirm that this problem exists and I am currently trying to resolve it myself in my app. If I find a solution I will let you know.

Comment: Seeing this on iOS 14.2 at `player.append()` after `player.setQueue(with:)`.  Adding a `player.prepareToPlay()` in-between the statements stopped the freezes in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm the issue is still present, but after doing some testing I found out that what it's actually doing is blocking the main thread from executing. So a workaround that at least worked for me is executing the play function inside the background thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()
}
```

Now the issue may still be present sometimes but i found that moving it to the background thread makes it way less tedious and less often. Also adding prepare to play also seems to make it work 99% of the time.

Comment: yup, this helped me too. Although, I'd suggest using your own serial queue instead because the MPMusicPlayerController started giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS failures on concurrent background threads. The docs note that we should use the main thread for MPMusicPlayerController, but I found a private serial queue works just as fine. I use something like `DispatchQueue(label: 'com.example.myqueue')`

Comment: This is effective for not freezing the UI, but I still get the issue and it delays actual start of music playback.